# How can I find exactly what my codesign identity is?

Tags: iphone, ios, code-signing, provisioning

I need to know exactly what my codesign identity is.  Where can I find that?  And what is the usual format for a codesign identity?  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xcode, you can access the Code Signing Identity by selecting your **target**, going to **build settings** and it's right under "*Code Signing Identity*".

For more information, you can access [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html).

Answer (score 56):

You can run following command in your terminal to get a list of all codesign identities installed on your system:

```
security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

The output will contain lines like:

```
1) 482348ADF834384843884934734 "iPhone Developer: John Smith (YTHGJFKTHG)"
2) 49u343943943943494387348738 ...
```

where the first part (482348ADF834384843884934734) is your codesign identity, which is passed as an argument to the `--sign` flag of `codesign` tool.

Comment: When I run that command I get no identities, any clue on how whould I fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

On macOS 11 Big Sur, @Taras answer above does not return any identities.
However, by removing `-v` for verbose, it does, and while it doesn't make any sense:

```
λ security find-identity -v -p codesigning
     0 valid identities found

λ security find-identity -p codesigning

Policy: Code Signing
  Matching identities
  1) B21272CXXXXXXCDBC562C0E0XXXXXX89 "Apple Development: Haakon Storm Heen (9X9X3XKX5X)"
     1 identities found

  Valid identities only
     0 valid identities found
```

Comment: In this case `-v` is not for _verbose_ but it means that only _valid_ identities should be displayed.

Comment: Wow, thank you @Oldes for the correction. Depending on context `-v` can mean verify but also verbose. How odd. Thanks for pointing this out.